# C++ "No such file or directory," please. I have the included headers! (C++ Primer)

Tags: c++, header

I don't know what I am doing wrong!

I have defined the header files: Project->Build Options->Search directories->Compiler->Added the path that my header file is located in...

I am using codeblocks.

I don't know what is wrong!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sales_item book; // Reads ISBN, number of copies sold and sales price
    cin >> book; // Write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and avg. price
    cout << book << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copy in your question full invocation of the compiler from the tab «Build output». It is something like `g++ main.cpp …`, *(below you will also see build errors)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple visit to the Code::Blocks wiki would have solved your problem.

The process:

`- Right click on the project then select Build options
- Select the directories tab
- Add the required paths for compiler and linker.
- Add your specific libraries in the linker tab.
- Pay attention to project settings and target settings.`

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've followed the steps and it is still giving me that error. Am I placing the file in the right folder? I am sure I am because I have the header in the folder.

Comment: Thanks, this is solved. I use CodeLite now instead of CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  < Sales_item.h>  instead "Sales_item.h". Not sure about CodeBlocks, but using "" usually means that the path is located in the same directory while <> means that path is described in the project settings.

Comment: Not quite right, and the "" syntax should fallback on the <> syntaxe on failure. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/77092/1614219

Comment: I meant usual general situation - not sure how CodeBlocks rework it

Comment: This is defined in the C++ standard so codeblocks should not interfere. See the answer I linked.

Comment: LOL. I was not going to teach anybody - I've proposed the possible way to resolve the problem.

Comment: Which is wrong, since the "" syntax fallbacks on the <> syntax on failure, as my link demonstrates. There is zero chance of a header being found by manually replacing "" with <>. Actually your compiler may find *less* headers with the <> syntax than with the "" syntax. I just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is because of `<iostream>`,
Goto `Settings -> Compiler... -> Global compiler settings -> Linker settings` then add path of directory folder into folder

If your issue is because of `"Sales_item.h"`, ensure that `Sales_item.h` was placed in the same directory with this (`main.cpp` I guess)